# Call to a member function where() on a non-object in ... on line 13

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I am new user of CodeIgniter, I am trying to create simple login page using CodeIgniter but I am receiving the following error:

> Call to a member function where() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIg\application\models\user.php on line 13

I am uncertain as to where to begin debugging this, suggestions would be appreciated.

**My code for the model is as follows:**

```
<?php
class User extends CI_model{  
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function verifyuser()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $remember = $this->input->post('remember'); 
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('user_login');
        $result = array();
        if($query->num_rows==0)
        {
            $result['false']=false;
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            $result=$query->result();
            foreach($result as $item)
            {
                $result['id']=$item->id;
                $result['username']=$item->username;
                $result['password']=$item->password;
            }
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**and code for controller is:**

```
<?php
    class User_Controller extends CI_controller
    {
        public function getloginData()
        {
            $this->load->model('User');
            $rvalue = $this->User->verifyuser();
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($rvalue);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Database is not initialized.
You need to include the "database" in your application/config/autoload.php:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Or in your model class constructor:

```
class User extends CI_model{ 

     public function __construct() 
     {
           parent::__construct(); 
           $this->load->database();
     }
}
```

You can get more information here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 1):

`$this->db` isn't initialized, so `$this->db` is null and calling where() on null results in this error.. you have to assign something to $this->db first.

To do this, you have to laod the Model within your controller